# Java DB path for GitHub distribution

Tags: java, github, derby

I have a project assignment in which I have to create a Java application. The program must be uploaded to my GitHub repository so my professor can see it and interact with it.

I have the following problem: For the purposes of the application I have to use a database. I decided to work with a Java Derby embedded database. So here an example of my code where I connect with the database:

```
String Table_click = (jTable1.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).toString());
Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");          
java.sql.Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:C:\\Users\\themi\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\HRCompanion\\databases\\Login", "root", "1234");
```

As you can see, my database is stored inside the project folder on my computer. But if I upload this code to GitHub, then my professor will not be able to run the application properly, as the database path does not exist. Is there a way to change the path to make the application work properly to a different computer?

Comment: You can give a try to ngrok. Your application will be hosted in your local environment and there will be a network tunnel to access your application.Meanwhile, you can share code over Github for review. I hope it will solve your problem.[https://ngrok.com/]

Comment: If you still want your application to be hosted on gitpages you can use firebase.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a relative path in your JDBC Connection URL.

So, for example, `jdbc:derby:db` means that Derby will look for the database in the `db` folder in the current directory.

Then you won't have such a problem with system-specific pathnames.